# difference between two dates in days in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two variables `date1=2023-10-08` and `date2=2023-10-09`
I want to calculate the difference between the two in days , I'm trying with:

```
 DIFF=$(( ($date2 - $date1) / (60 * 60 * 24) ))
if [ $DIFF -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "one day ago.."
    else
        echo "many dayzz"
fi
```

I'm getting this error:

```
(2023-10-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

Comment: Convert the dates to seconds since the epoch and then do the calculation.

Comment: Avoid using ALLCAPS variable names (e.g. `DIFF`), all capital names are reserved for shell use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash arithmetic cannot process date within this format. Dates must be converted to integers with a tool such as `date`. Using GNU `date`'s `%s`, one can compute the difference with

```
$(( ($(date -d "$date2" "+%s") - $(date -d "$date1" "+%s")) / 86400 ))
```